# yml parsing error for my pipiline in gitlab

Tags: yaml

I was creating my yml file to create a pipiline and compile my code in github.

This is my file and I cannot understand why is not parsing correctly. I already checked all spaces. If someone can help me I will really appreciate it.

```
    .regression

  image: node-16-alpine

  default:
    tags:
      - mycompany-services-internal-running

    script:
      - git clone https://mycode.com
      - npm install
      - npm run myCodeExample
      - node myReport.js

    artifact:
      -reports/cucumber_report.html
```

Comment: `-reports/cucumber_report.html` misses a space after the dash. Because of that, the value of `artifact` key is not a list but a dash-prefixed string. You could easily find that in any online YAML validator.

Comment: i already fixed this issue and used yaml validator and the issue apparently is in line 3 (image: node-16-alpine) and i cannot understand why.. any idea ? -the error is end of the stream or a document separator is expected (3:8)-

Comment: Well, if `.regression` is actually part of your document, then it is definitely mis-intended.